# how to know item in dropdown is selected or not nd then show popup

Tags: drop-down-menu

I have the button on which i am showing the popup window. this button is diabled while page laod. When I'll select the item from dropdown on same form the button will be enabled. ok ? But second time it will remain as it is means enabled. I want to restrict button click till the item will select from Dropdown. How to do?

Comment: What language/technology are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are talking about a web application, you can do this using JavaScript.

You can set a variable on the 'onchange' event for the drop down list.

**[onchange event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536912%28VS.85%29.aspx)** fires when the contents of the object or selection have changed.